# Java regex special character in returned string

Tags: java, regex

I'm mostly coding in Perl and struggle now with a regex in Java. I have this:

```
// String dbfPath = "/result_feature/Monocytes-CD14+_H3K4me3_ENCODE_UW_bwa_samse"
// rs.getString = "Monocytes-CD14+_H3K4me3_ENCODE_UW_bwa_samse"

if(! dbfPath.matches(".*" + rs.getString("rs_name") + "/*"))
```

My problem is that the rs_name contains wildcards (+). I tried putting [] around, but then I have an illegal range (-).

How can I avoid the returning string being interpreted?

Thanks!

Comment: If you thought `[]` would help you should probably read a regex tutorial.

Comment: put the symbol `-` at first or at the last inside character class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `rs.getString()` inside a `Pattern.quote`:

```
Pattern.quote(rs.getString("rs_name"))
```

> Returns a literal pattern String for the specified String.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Pattern.quote(rs.getString("rs_name"))` to automatically escape control characters.

Beware of `null`s.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`java.util.regex.Pattern.qoute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)):

```
if(! dbfPath.matches(".*" + java.util.regex.Pattern.qoute(rs.getString("rs_name") ) + "/*"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add '\Q' & '\E' in your string direclty.

```
\Q  Nothing, but quotes all characters until \E
\E  Nothing, but ends quoting started by \Q





if(! dbfPath.matches(".*\\Q" + rs.getString("rs_name") + "\\E/*"))
```

One thing, you should make sure your string doesn't contain '\E', if yes, the safe way is using Pattern.quote() methods.